# "no main manifest attribute" even setting Main-Class in manifest file

Tags: java, jar, manifest

It's my first time using this forum for ask a question.

I'm beggining to learn Java, and I need some help.

I'm trying to create a jar file, without specifying the class. I found out, that I must create a Manifest.mf file, and writing Main-Class: ClassName into it.

Even doing this, it's returning "no main manifest attribute" error.

Thats my class:

```
package testing;
class Teste{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

My manifest file (Manifest.mf):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_101 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: testing.Test
```

First of all, I compiled it using javac, and the Test.class was automatically created.

Secondly, I created the jar file using the following command in cmd:

```
jar -cvfm Test.jar Manifest.mf *.class
```

Finally, I executed it using:

```
java -jar Test.jar
```

Thanks from Brazil!

Comment: Spelling matters.  Your class is named `Teste` (five letters), so your Main-Class value has to be `testing.Teste`.

Comment: I tried testing.Test in manifest file

Comment: You need to change that.  You don’t have a class named Test, you have a class named `Teste`.